# How to quickly find a point that can generate largest absolute value of slope from top left

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, graph-theory

Suppose we have a series of points in the first quadrant of coordinates. For each point (x1, y1), how to find a point (x2, y2), x2 < x1, y2 ≥ y1, so that (y2 - y1) / (x1 - x2) is the largest.

The brute force approach is for each point (x1, y1), find all (x2, y2), x2 < x1, y2 ≥ y1, calculate all possible (y2 - y1) / (x1 - x2) and compare, and finally get the maximum value for each point, so the time complexity for each point is O(n), and the total time complexity is O(n²).

Do we have a faster way to solve it?

Comment: @sharpnife No need to call `abs`, we already know that `abs(x1-x2) = x1-x2` and `abs(y2-y1) = y2-y1`

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If I am right, this is exactly achived by the Graham's walk for the incremental construction of the convex hull, in the monotone chain variant (Andrew's algorithm, lower hull).

If the points are already sorted, this only takes time O(N).

On this example, the most positive slopes are 01, 23, 24, 45, 26 and 67.

[image]

Comment: The idea is really great! I wonder if we can take up Andrew's algorithm but without sorting points (maybe a divide-and-conquer algorithm...)

Comment: @0009laH: nope.

Comment: @0009laH: we do know. A convex hull algorithm does sort and this is why its complexity is Ω(N log N).

Comment: Where did I write that we must produce a convex hull algorithm? Andrew's one gives an idea but I don't wish to copy-paste the whole process.

Comment: @0009laH: the problem asked *does* construct the convex hull. And yeah, the output-sensitive complexity is O(N Log H), not O(N log N) but in the worst case H=N.

Comment: How do we know this is the only approach to find the steepest line between two points?

Comment: @0009laH: this does not matter, any solution to the problem asked does construct the convex hull, whatever the approach. And the convex hull problem is proven to be Ω(N log N).